# intellij idea cannot resolve symbol on built-in methods

Tags: java, ide, intellij-14

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA IDE and I have some problems with it. It seems the IDE does know the built-in methods for arrays and arraylist (`add()`, `remove()`...). It marks them red "cannot resolve symbol".

I tried the cache thing and reinstalled the IDE. I got 14.1.5 ultimate and I tried Comunity Edition as well but it's not working.

I got a new problem. It seems the IDE does not know `for` and `if` loops.

Also, one time they were recognized but the colors of the refrences ("used to be violet") turned white.

Comment: Use real English words, not "cuz, wanna, im, etc.". And stop cracking software. IntelliJ has a free community edition. use that.

Comment: jeez , consider that english is not my language ,, and cracking is not our subject please be relevant !!

Comment: So what, it's not mine either. And that's why I can read your question much easier if it uses real words rather than slang. I doubt your English teacher taught you that "I want to do this because" is spelt "i wanna do this cuz". You **chose** to use slang, and it's not appropriate.

Comment: DO YOU HAVE A SOLUTION ? ok guess not!

Comment: HAVE YOU POSTED THE CODE AND THE ERROR MESSAGE? Your main problem is that you think your code is perfect, your question is perfect, and we are stupid, and so is your IDE. But hey, you have a problem, and we don't. So stay as is. It has proven to be efficient, right?

Comment: OMG dude i'm so stupid ... i'm an idiot i went through my code over and over and i found that the main() method is not there ,im sorry man, offf i'm so stupid , i'm going to stop programming , i'm embarrassed .

Comment: Glad you sorted it out. Tough lesson learnt: usually, it's your fault. Remember it: it will last for your whole career.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you have a JDK installed and selected the Project SDK (under Project Structure -> Project).